# Unable to check checkbox while doing selenium webdriver automation

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to check checkbox but unable to do. Below are the alternates that i've tried till now :

1. `(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")).click();`
2. `(driver.findElement(By.name("selectedUpgCtn")).click();`
3. `JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;`

   ```
   js1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")));
   ```
4. `js.executeScript("document.getElementByName('selectedUpgCtn').click()");`
5. `(driver.findElement(By.name("selectedUpgCtn")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`
6. `(driver.findElement(By.name("selectedUpgCtn")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
7. the above 2 ways i have tried using xpath as well.

I have written code to wait, to check if the element is enabled or not, to check if element is clickable or not..but still can't check it. I'm also not getting any issue like element not found etc. the script simply stops there.Below is the code of that checkbox:

```
<input name="selectedUpgCtn" class="floatLeft ctncheckbox_6784290495 "type="checkbox"value="6784290495"targetsrc="wirelessUpgradeEligibilityModule" targetevent="disableStartUpgrade">
```

Any help would be really appreciated...

Comment: <input name="selectedUpgCtn" class="floatLeft ctncheckbox_6784290495 " type="checkbox" value="6784290495" targetsrc="wirelessUpgradeEligibilityModule" targetevent="disableStartUpgrade">------ this is the code of that checkbox....

Comment: Check the HTML code in BOTH states (checked and unchecked) to see if there's a difference.  You might find a new attribute appear or one of the attributes (possibly Value) change.

Comment: I just checked the html code in both states but there's no change in its code...but there is a button present at the bottom of the page....this button gets enabled and disabled with checking and unchecking the checkbox...

Comment: Have you checked for the presence of an IFRAME as the answer below suggests?  That's the only other thing I can think of as well.

Comment: The element is present inside an iFrame and i'm already switching my frame to that frame....also just to see if element is being found or not i'm printing one of the attributes of this checkbox element just before clicking it with below code :- System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")).getAttribute("name")); and this print statement is giving me expected o/p

Comment: If the element you are looking for is in an `IFRAME`, make sure you are switching to the right `IFRAME` and that it's not nested in yet another `IFRAME`. A link to the page would solve this issue.

Comment: @JeffC....as i said...just to see if my locator code is correct or not...i'm printing something on the console and its giving me correct o/p....i have posted that print statement above...

Comment: Code doesn't just simply stop on a line with no error. You have other code or a framework that is likely eating that error. That's why you need to post an [mcve] that you are actually running so we don't have to keep asking all these questions to try to get at the root of the issue. You're supposed to have done that before posting.

Comment: this is what was actually happening...i was not getting error otherwise i would have resolved it..and just to check if some other code is not eating up the error...i comment out the remaining code...and then my script was just getting stopped without clicking that element....but just now i tried with Andrie's code and finally its working...

Comment: please don't ruin your question by showing alternatives that DON'T work

Comment: i didn't understand...how would showing all the alternatives that i had tried till then ruined my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly your element is in `frame` of `iframe`, that's why try to find frame/iframe and use this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame selector"); // switch to frame 
// now you are able to ineract with all elements inside it
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")).click(); // locate your element
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // switch back to default content
```

You are not able to interact with elements inside `iframe` or `frame` without switching to it's content.

Also try to wait for element until it will be clickable:

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")));
element.click();
```

**EDIT:** Now you are able to locate the element, now you want to click on it, but it is not working. Try to use:

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

This will simulate an actions chains => move to element and then click on it.

Or:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;   
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")));
```

Also I have faced at some of my tests, that some elements not getting clicked at the first time, but if I click on them two times and add some pause between first click and second click, it works. Try this also out.

Comment: The element is present inside an iFrame and i'm already switching my frame to that frame....also just to see if element is being found or not i'm printing one of the attributes of this checkbox element just before clicking it with below code :- System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedUpgCtn']")).getAttribute("name")); and this print statement is giving me expected o/p.

Comment: What  means o/p?

Comment: i just now tried using the WebDriverWait code that you posted but its neither checking that checkbox nor is it giving any error.....

Comment: I don't understand you, did you get your issue solved or not?

Comment: by o/p i mean....the value of the attribute "name" which is "selectedUpgCtn".........this is getting printed on my console....that means my locator code is able to find the checkbox but somehow its not getting checked...after implementing your WebDriverWait code i think the click method is getting executed properly but there's something which is preventing my checkbox to get checked....

Comment: I see, try to use Javascript executor (third in your post) to click

Comment: I have added information to my answer, please have a look

Comment: I had tried action chain as well but that didn't work...but..just now i tried using javascript executor right after webdriverwait and guess what...it worked :D .... i have been struggling with this for the past 2 days...thanks a ton Andrie :)

Comment: Happy to hear it! Then you can mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button